# Can 'For this,' be used as an introductory phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage

The two phrases I have are:

> I created a 'Terms and Conditions' document. For this, I used multiple terms and condition documents from other companies.

The 'For this, ' part doesn't sound so well, but is it grammatically correct?

Comment: I see nothing ungrammatical about it.

Comment: The phrase "Doesn't sound so well" doesn't sound so **good** to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as grammar goes, it is perfectly fine.

As far as how "vernacular" it is, it should be fine. The one thing I would find odd about it is if you were talking face-to-face and didn't have a copy of the document with you, in which case I would switch the word "this" out and replace it with "that."